# SpringBoot Application: Accessing Common application properties in a JSP page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jstl, spring-el

I'm trying to access a property set in my application.properties in a JSP page. This is for display purposes which sends a user to a different application from our admin page. Its not needed in code at all.

application.properties entry:

```
frontend.url=http://example.com/some_endpoint
```

In my JSP file
I've tried these variations below.

```
<spring:eval  expression="('frontend.url')" />
<spring:eval  expression="'frontend.url'" />
```

These below throw errors

```
<spring:eval  expression="@getProperty('frontend.url')" />
<spring:eval  expression="@frontend.url" />
<spring:eval  expression="@applicationProperties.getProperty('frontend.url')" />
```

Is there a specific syntax to use or should I just expose a request attribute from a controller?

```
@Value("${frontend.url}")
private String urlForDisplayPurposes;
```

I know the proposed method explained here [enter link description here](http://javaninja.net/2014/01/how-to-use-spring-properties-values-in-a-jsp/)
works but I really don't want an extra properties file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `@environment.getProperty()` should work. For example:

```
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('frontend.url')" var="frontendUrl" />
<a href="${frontendUrl}">Click</a>
```

For this to work, you need to include the Spring taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="springframework.org/tags" %>
```

Comment: And you have to add spring taglib to page: <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

Answer (score 2):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('myvar')" var="frontendUrl" />
```

and you can use "frontendUrl" in jsp